# Listen to changes to element's content length or presence of a scrollbar in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, observable, scrollbar, overflow

I have a container with `overflow-y: auto` and I need to shift the rest of my layout depending on whether its scrollbar is present or not.

I know I can check for scrollbar's presence at any given time:

```
const scrollbarVisible = (e) => e.scrollHeight > e.clientHeight
```

But I don't know how to listen/observe for the scrollbar's presence in order to trigger a re-render of my side-dock.

What are my options? Do I have any besides checking for the scrollbar in regular intervals with `setInterval` to detect the change that way?

Comment: Checking within `useLayoutEffect` inside the component that renders my container unfortunately doesn't do the job, because it contains many redux-connected sub-components that re-render independently.

Comment: Also, I cannot reliably identify all actions that might result in the change of content's length and check manually, because there are just way too many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [resize observer api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-hook/resize-observer) to check for size changes in an element. An example of usage, also present in the link I mentioned, follows:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import useResizeObserver from '@react-hook/resize-observer'

const useSize = (target) => {
  const [size, setSize] = React.useState()

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setSize(target.current.getBoundingClientRect())
  }, [target])

  // Where the magic happens
  useResizeObserver(target, (entry) => setSize(entry.contentRect))
  return size
}

const App = () => {
  const target = React.useRef(null)
  const size = useSize(target)
  return (
    <pre ref={target}>
      {JSON.stringify({width: size.width, height: size.height}, null, 2)}
    </pre>
  )
}
```

After that you can check for the overflow as you did with JS

Comment: Of course, a resize listener on the container's content - why haven't I thought of this? :)

Comment: Oh, so it's actually an observer, not a listener, listener only works on `window` - haven't known that. Anyway, this solved my problem, works like a charm. Thank you very much for the tip!